# Create an Admob native ad programmatically

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I am trying to setup native ads from Admob programmatically but there is nearly no documentation about it from the official guide available [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express). 
I think I am close to the solution but I don't see how to set the unit size on it.

The documentation says:

> Publishers can also use the FULL_WIDTH constant when programmatically creating an AdSize for a NativeExpressAdView.

The problem is that this `FULL_WIDTH` unit is not an `AdSize` unit like the other ones available, it just returns an integer.

Here is what I got for now:

```
mAdmobNativeExpressAdview = new NativeExpressAdView(this);
mAdmobNativeExpressAdview.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.mediation_native_id));
mAdmobNativeExpressAdview.setAdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH);
```

But the last line cannot be implemented since the `setAdSize` is expecting an `AdSize` object.

Is there another way to set this attribute?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at the sample found in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/ads/NativeExpressAdView)

`mNativeExpressAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(400, 100));`

Where

`AdSize` constructor is [declared](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize#public-constructor-summary) as

> AdSize(int width, int height)
>
> Create a new AdSize.

In your code:

`mAdmobNativeExpressAdview.setAdSize(new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, 20));`

For example, sets the advert size to take up the full width, with height of 20dp.

Adjust to suit your layout.

Comment: Yes thanks, I actually also just found the same answer in this Admob Team answer on their forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/1swPzC2BUQo